# hidden_field_tag doesn't allow me to pass empty array - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.2.1.

My User model (using mongoid):

```
class User

    field :first_name,           :type => String
    field :last_name,            :type => String
    field :email,                :type => String
    field :roles,                :type => Array,     :default => []

end
```

then, my `edit.html.erb` (relevant part):

```
<%= f.label :roles %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'user[roles][]', [] %>
    <% roles = Tools::Utils.load_roles %>
    <% @roles.each do |role| %>
        <li>
            <%= check_box_tag('user[roles][]', role, @user.roles.include?(role.downcase))%>
            <%= h role %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
```

When I get to the edit view:

[image]

Then I uncheck:

[image]

And submit. this is the `params` that I get in UsersController:

```
{"user"=>
  {
   "first_name"=>"test",
   "last_name"=>"test",
   "email"=>"test@test.com",
   "roles"=>[""]
   }
}
```

Note `"roles"=>[""]`. I get an array with an empty string instead of just an empty array (desired).

How can I achieve this? I tried multiple ways, but none seems to work.

Comment: If it's empty, and you have a default, why pass anything?

Comment: @davenewton Because in the case it is already populated, if I want it to be blank again I need to pass that information.

Answer (score 0):

### Add `before_save` callback to remove blank Strings from your Array.

*`user.rb`*

```rb
before_save :remove_empty_strings_from_roles

def remove_empty_strings_from_roles
  self.roles.reject!( &:blank? )
end
```

Note, in Rails 6+, you can use [`self.roles.compact_blank`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank) instead of `self.roles.reject!( &:blank? )`.

Answer (score -1):

Which `value` have Your `checkbox`? 
So it have value equil `an empty string`.

When You render form, this value don't was checked becouse `default: []`,
but browser send value `as it look for`...

You should write:

> field :roles,                :type => Array,     :default => ['none']

and I hope it help You!